# How to write in typescript the function indexOf for arrays?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, indexof

I am trying to use the function `arr.indexOf` with Typescript:

```
const index: number = batches.indexOf((batch: BatchType) => (batch.id === selectedBatchId))
```

`BatchType` is following type:

```
export default interface BatchType {
  id: number,
  month: number,
  year: number
}
```

`batches` are coming from a context, without types:

```
const initState = {
  dance: {
    id: '',
    name: ''
  },
  level: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    schedule: ''
  },
  batches: []
}
```

I use this `initState` in the `useState` hook:

const [level, setLevel] = useState(initState)

In my component, I use the `batches` within the `level` object.

The error that I get is the following:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(batch: BatchType) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Why is treating a type including the `=> boolean`. Where is he complaining? Who is type `never`? `batches`? `batch`?

I had the feeling that the problem comes from the `batches` object, that in the provider I am not using types, but Typescript is not complaining for this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in array-method `indexOf` does not take a callback as its argument, it takes an element to look for in the array. If the element is contained in the array, it will return the first index of that element, if the element is not in the array, it will return -1.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf:

```
const beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];

console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison'));
// expected output: 1
```

So typescript is complaining that you are giving indexOf an argument with a wrong type: you are giving it a predicate with the type `(batch: BatchType) => boolean`.

I'm not totally sure about `never` - but since typescript is trying to infer types, my guess is that the argument to `indexOf` is inferred to be "a member of the array: []". Since there is no member of an empty array, the type is inferred to be `never`. Anyone know this for sure?

Comment: my bad, I had two docus opened, and actually the solution was under findIndex method. Since I am learning TS, I was focused on the error of ts, and not that the method was wrong. Apologize for this error